# How to convert bunch of .pcd files into .pcap?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, lidar

ROS provides tools to convert LiDAR PCAP file to PCD files. Assuming the LiDAR frequency is 10Hz, a 5 second PCAP can be converted to 50 .PCD pointclouds. Now given 50 .pcd files, am I able to convert them to a single PCAP file?

Comment: Is any information in the conversion from a PCAP file to multiple PCD files lost? If not, it's probably possible.

Comment: Basically, I have the PCAP, but my goal is to trip the pointcloud and make a new PCAP.

Comment: Yes, and if no information is lost when the PCAP is converted to PCD files, it should be possible to re-create the PCAP again - unless you make changes in the PCD files and the PCAP contains some tricky checksums or something. As long as you have the description of both file formats it should at least be possible to investigate if it's possible before starting to code.